# how to uppercase a string on specific position using comma as delimiter?

Tags: sed

If i have a text file with comma as delimiter, how do i count delimiter and change from lower to uppercase on 3rd delimiter?
If i have text file like this:

```
alex pallex, bakerstreet 5, 87236, ducktales, 213445  
Donald Duck, weebfoot street 1313, 12345, duckburg, 212344
```

And i want to have upper case on string after the 3rd comma, how do i do that using sed . 
ducktales changes to DUCKTALES och duckburg to DUCKBURG
I know there is AWk but i need to use sed.

Comment: Take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: wrt `i need to use sed` is that because an awk solution would be too clear, too robust, too portable, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [GNU `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html):

```bash
$ sed 's/[^,]*/\U&/4' file
alex pallex, bakerstreet 5, 87236, DUCKTALES, 213445  
Donald Duck, weebfoot street 1313, 12345, DUCKBURG, 212344
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using awk you'd:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{$4=toupper($4)}1' file
alex pallex, bakerstreet 5, 87236, DUCKTALES, 213445  
Donald Duck, weebfoot street 1313, 12345, DUCKBURG, 212344
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file.txt
alex pallex, bakerstreet 5, 87236, ducktales, 213445
Donald Duck, weebfoot street 1313, 12345, duckburg, 212344

$ sed 's/\([^\,]*\,[^\,]*\,[^\,]*\,\)\([^\,]*\)/\1\U\2/' file.txt
alex pallex, bakerstreet 5, 87236, DUCKTALES, 213445
Donald Duck, weebfoot street 1313, 12345, DUCKBURG, 212344
```

Not sure if no escape would work, but you can try:

```
sed 's/\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\)\([^,]*\)/\1\U\2/' file.txt
```

Anyway, it's bothersome, if you have GNU sed, [PesaThe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54149750/5403468) is great.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: You definitely do not need to escape `,`s as a comma is not a metacharacter.